# Как лучше реализовать карту

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу написать игру на python в стиле mud игр или текстовый квест. Мне нужно сделать карту, чтобы персонаж мог по ней перемещаться командами и выводить ее на экран через print. Пишу на чистом питоне, игра консольная. Была идея сделать её через новый класс в который добавить массив map и сделать что-то вроде такого

```
class Map():
    map = []
    def __init__(self):
        map.append([w, w, w, w])
        map.append([w, 0, 0, w])
        map.append([w, 0, 0, w])
        map.append([w, w, w, w])
```

Но у меня так и не получилось довести этот метод до рабочего прототипа, так как появились проблемы с выводом карты на экран.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

не лучшая идея в MUD играх реализовывать карту в виде 2D карты со стенами, не эффективно

почему бы вам не использовать систему, которую изначально в MUD играх и используется, т.е. систему комнат и выходов

т.е. есть класс `Room`, в которой есть список выходов (можно сделать как фиксированный список из 14 ссылок на другие комнаты или как словарь типа

```
{'n': room1, 'u': room2}
```

и отрисовку такого списка комнат уже можно делать на 2D карту, которую и выводить на экран

типа такого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как можно строить карту:**

1. берём произвольную комнату и ставим ей координату (0,0) (считаем что вверх и вниз не двигаемся),
2. дальше начинам обходить все комнаты - если комната на севере, то у нее координата будет уже (0,-1) и т.д. и заодно каждый раз вычисляем `min_x`, `max_x`, `min_y`, `max_y`,
3. после первого обхода комнат у нас будет размер игрового поля `(max_x - min_x, max_y - min_y)`, строим двумерный массив,
4. затем опять обходим комнаты и уже в двумерном массиве по координатам (где `min_x = 0`, `min_y = 0`) рисуем что нам надо,
5. а затем выводим 2D массив

уже дальше алгоритм можно усложнять:

1. учесть вертикальные направления движения - тогда карта будет уже трехмерной, а наложение на двухмерность придется делать через добавление лишних рядов и колонок на двухмерной карте
2. учесть, что расстояние между соседними комнатами может быть больше 0

Comment: Т.е. создать класс room, содержащий в себе только выходы на другие комнаты... Я немного не понимаю, как тогда строить карту для отрисовки...

Comment: @Corengenie, именно так. Как можно строить карту - берём произвольную комнату и ставим ей координату (0,0) (считаем что вверх и вниз не двигаемся), и дальше начинам обходить все комнаты - если комната на севере, то у нее координата будет уже (0,-1) и т.д. и заодно каждый раз вычисляем `min_x`, `max_x`, `min_y`, `max_y`, после первого обхода комнат у нас будет размер игрового поля `(max_x - min_x, max_y - min_y)`, строим двумерный массив, затем опять обходим комнаты и уже в двумерном массиве по координатам (где `min_x = 0`, `min_y = 0`) рисуем что нам надо, а затем выводим 2d массив как у Danis

Comment: @Zhihar думаю это лучше написать в ответе

Answer (score 2):

красивый вывод можно сделать так:

```
def pprint(map):
    for line in map:
        print(*line, sep = "")
```